# How the time complexity of gcd is Θ(logn)?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, greatest-common-divisor, big-o

I was solving a time-complexity question on Interview Bit as given in the below image.
[image]

The answer given is `Θ(theta)(logn)` and I am not able to grasp how the logn term arrive here in the time complexity of this program.

Can someone please explain how the answer is theta of logn?

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem** given any x, gcd(n, m) where n < fib(x) is recursive called equal or less than x times.

Note: fib(x) is fibonacci(x), where fib(x) = fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)

**Prove**

**Basis**

every n <= fib(1), gcd(n, m) is gcd(1,m) only recursive once

**Inductive step**

assume the theorem is hold for every number less than x, which means:

```
calls(gcd(n, m)) <= x for every n <= fib(x)
```

consider n where n <= fib(x+1)

if m > fib(x)

```
   calls(gcd(n, m))
=  calls(gcd(m, (n-m))) + 1
=  calls(gcd(n-m, m%(n-m))) + 2  because n - m <= fib(x-1)
<= x - 1 + 2
=  x + 1
```

if m <= fib(x)

```
   calls(gcd(n, m))
=  calls(gcd(m, (n%m))) + 1  because m <= fib(x)
<= x + 1
```

So the theorem also holds for x + 1, as mathematical induction, the theorem holds for every x.

**Conclusion**

gcd(n,m) is Θ(reverse fib) which is Θ(logn)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm generates a decreasing sequence of integer `(m, n)` pairs. We can try to prove that such sequence decays fast enough.

Let's say we start with `m_1` and `n_1`, with `m_1 < n_1`.

At each step we take `n_1 % m_1`, which is `< m_1`, and repeat recursively on the pair `m_2 = n_1 % m_1` and `n_2 = m_1`.

Now, let's say `n_1 % m_1 = m_1 - p` for some `p` where `0 < p < m_1`.
We have `max(m_2, n_2) = m_1 - p`.

Let's take another step `(m_2, n_2) -> (m_3, n_3)`, we can easily see that `max(m_3, n_3) < p`, but clearly it is also true that `max(m_3, n_3) < m_1 - p` as the sequence is strictly decreasing.

So we can write `max(m_3, n_3) < min(m_1 - p, p)`, where `min(m_1 - p, p) = m_1 / 2`. This result expresses the fact that the sequence decreases geometrically, therefore the algorithm has to terminate in at most `log_2(m_1)` steps.